# Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric. - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy tratando de convertir un campo numeric a varchar y no puedo

```
CAST(( CAST(o.SaldoCapital AS NUMERIC(14, 2)) ) AS VARCHAR(16))
```

este error me genera, alguien me puede ayudar?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cuál es el tipo de dato original de `SaldoCapital`?

Comment: es Numeric(19,4)

Comment: ahí está el motivo entonces, lo estás convirtiendo a un formato más "pequeño" y no cabe

Comment: Si lo que quieres es bajar la precisión de la mantisa (la parte fraccionaria), hay mejores opciones que esa.

Comment: Ya tengo otro campo con las mismas caracteristicas y funciona perfecto de esa forma, solo este campo arroja el error no entiendo porque

de que otra forma puedo realizarlo?

Comment: simplemente porque el "otro campo" no tiene un valor tan grande. O sea, el tema es que tienes algún dato que por ejemplo tiene más de 14 dígitos en uso, y por consiguiente no se puede convertir al tipo de dato que quieres, no hay más motivos que eso

Comment: el valor mas alto de ese campo es 7200101301006.2220, ¿Como deberia de realizar la conversion?

Comment: pero ahí está más o menos claro, no?, tienes un número que contiene 13 dígitos en la parte entera, y 3 dígitos más en la parte decimal....un total de 16 dígitos. No estoy seguro cómo quieres convertirlo en un numeric de 14 dígitos?